# svn error can't create directory under .svn\pristine

Tags: svn, teamcity

Really strange error that started happening suddenly (i.e nothing in the workflow changed) , the symptom is that the teamcity build hang on checking out sources, then I try to go to svn and do the checkout manually and I get:

```
Error: Can't move  
Error:  'D:\TeamCity_buildAgent\BuildAgent\work\adeda1932e08092f\.svn\tmp\svn-82F432C7'  
Error:  to  
Error:  'D:\TeamCity_buildAgent\BuildAgent\work\adeda1932e08092f\.svn\pristine\59\5909d29d95ea2293ffcaedf15b79278fcb6af65e.svn-base':  
Error:  The system cannot find the path specified.  
Error: Can't create directory  
Error:  'D:\TeamCity_buildAgent\BuildAgent\work\adeda1932e08092f\.svn\pristine\59':  
Error:  The system cannot find the path specified.
```

What I tried so far:

- Delete folder and checkout again
- clean up
- clean up with all the options on
- many other things ...

Context

- large repo (over 5Gb)
- svn 1.7
- Win7
- Lots of free disk space
- error present only on build machine so far on that particular folder, the error shows up on tortoise svn, on teamcity it just hangs
- Error occurs only on this folder on the teamcity
- I can checkout fine the whole repository from tortoisesvn

The weird thing is there is noting obvious about the source of the problem. Teamcity was just starting to update because it received new changes the first time I saw this. The change in question was a modification to an existing file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to restart the build server, after that a clean build worked.

It appears that some file got locked and couldn't be deleted and that put svn in a strange state

Sorry that this isn't more interesting

Answer (score 1):

What exactly were you attempting when you got the error? Were you moving the repository over? Adding a file? Was this something TeamCity was trying to do? If so, what was TeamCity trying to do when the error hit.

That would help me understand what the system was attempting to do.

The file name is long. Windows does not gracefully handle file names longer than 255 characters including the path. Sometimes, I've seen C# projects with a file directory structure where file names get overly long. Besides, that file name is only 122 characters long.

See if you can look at the console and see what command was being executed when that error occurred.

Comment: That is part of the problem there is noting obvious about the source of the problem. Teamcity was just starting to update because it received new changes the first time I saw this. The change in question was a modification to an existing file.

Comment: Look at two things on this TeamCity server: See if `D:\TeamCity_buildAgent\BuildAgent\work\adeda1932e08092f\.svn\pristine\59` exists as a directory (TeamCity said it couldn't find it). See if you, as the TeamCity user, can update the working copy via the `svn update` command line client. This will pinpoint whether there's an issue with the working copy, or TeamCity. It might also give you a better error message too. BTW, I take it TeamCity is using the SVN API for checkout and updating.

Comment: No, just committing a modified file, name was already committed. the command was a simple update   @david W the file was not there and the error showing in the message above was what was happening when I ran svn update on a console